# How to Query MongoDB using Spring JPA along with StartingWIth

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

My mongo db has documents with `_id` defined as `string`. Typical values for `_id` s are

- `abc#1234`
- `abc#2345`
- `aby#5678`.
- `abx#123`

I want to do a prefix query around `abc#` to return `abc#1234` `abc#2345` (given that _id are sorted in Mongo, I think the prefix query will be efficient --more efficient than 2ndry indexes --Please correct me if I am wrong)

I tried the below and it returned a list of size 0.

```
@Repository
public interface DBEntityRespository  extends MongoRepository<DBEntity, String> {
    public List<DBEntity> findByIdStartingWith(String id);
}
```

entity is defined as...

```
@Document(collection = "someDBEntity")
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DBEntity {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private String id;
...
...
...
}
```

I am calling the repository as follows

```
   @GetMapping("/v1/x")
    public String hi(){
        List<DBEntity> list = repo.findByIdStartingWith("abc");// << tried with ^abc , /abc/, abc.* but no luck
        System.out.println(list.size() ); // << returns list of size 0
        return "success";
    }
```

Any thoughts on how to get the issue fixed? and return the full documents matching the prefix `abc` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query

```
@Query("{ 'id' : { $regex: '^?0', $options: 'i' } }")
public List<DBEntity> findByIdStartingWith(String id);
```